# How can I include an external javascript library to my react js project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, libraries

I am trying to add the following library to my project https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js but can't seem to find a way.

Comment: can you elaborate? how have you tried to add it? what specific issues are occurring?

Comment: https://github.com/webrtc/adapter they explain it on their page

Comment: npm install webrtc-adapter

Comment: Read about NPM and ES6 import

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm install webrtc-adapter` and then import it like you would normally do using `import 'webrtc-adapter'` or `require('webrtc-adapter')`.